# bundler install works, but gems are not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

I'm getting to a strange behavior:

`bundle install` works just fine and it installs everything properly. `wicked_pdf` was correctly installed by bundler:

```
DEBUG [7879938b]    Using wicked_pdf (0.9.10)
```

But when I start unicorn to run the app, I get:

```
 INFO starting unicorn
 INFO [b1c58c46] Running /usr/bin/env sudo /etc/init.d/unicorn_shop start on server
DEBUG [b1c58c46] Command: cd /var/www/shop/releases/20140201010816 && /usr/bin/env sudo /etc/init.d/unicorn_shop start
DEBUG [b1c58c46]    stdin: is not a tty
DEBUG [b1c58c46]    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92:in `block in materialize': Could not find wicked_pdf-0.9.10 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
DEBUG [b1c58c46]        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `map!'
DEBUG [b1c58c46]        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `materialize'
DEBUG [b1c58c46]        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:133:in `specs'
DEBUG [b1c58c46]        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:178:in `specs_for'
DEBUG [b1c58c46]        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:167:in `requested_specs'
DEBUG [b1c58c46]        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/environment.rb:18:in `requested_specs'
DEBUG [b1c58c46]        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:13:in `setup'
DEBUG [b1c58c46]        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler.rb:119:in `setup'
DEBUG [b1c58c46]        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/setup.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
DEBUG [b1c58c46]        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
DEBUG [b1c58c46]        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
cap aborted!
```

These logs are caught from my execution of capistrano, although I get a similar error when I run the two commands `bundle install` and `sudo service unicorn start` from the shell.

I'm not sure why unicorn is looking for the wicked_pdf gem in `/var/lib/gems` the gem for wicked_pdf is at `~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/wicked_pdf-0.9.10`

any clue?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like unicorn uses your system ruby (ignoring RVM and its gemsets). Try to set default ruby version and gemset, or switch to required combination right before starting the server by using wrapper script.

Here is [a link to RVM docs about solving this issue](https://rvm.io/integration/init-d).

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be the problem, I'm trying to follow the rvm docs, but it doesn't seem to work, it's not creating the file, `/usr/local/rvm/wrappers/my_app/unicorn`

and when I run the command with `--no-links` rvm says, that's all he would do. I'm confused

Comment: It seems to work now, that I have explicitly written which unicorn to use in the init.d unicorn script.